# CreateEvent fails (event already exists in \BaseNamedObjects)

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Some time ago I wrote a small Win32 test application which did nothing else than creating an event to be used to synchronize between two processes. Coming back I was stunned by the fact that the process with `CreateEvent` would return with error 5 (access denied), even when run as adminstrator.

```
ghWriteEvent = CreateEvent( 
    NULL,                       // default security attributes
    FALSE,                      // auto-reset event
    FALSE,                      // initial state is nonsignaled
    TEXT("Global\\WriteEvent")  // object name
    ); 

if (ghWriteEvent == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
```

After some debugging I decided to change the events' name and suddenly it worked. By chance I decided to look at the event creation/deletion in WinObj and I saw why it failed: there already was an event called `WriteEvent` under `\BaseNamedObjects`.

What could I have possibly done to make a named event *persistent* across reboots and more importantly, how can I get rid of it?

---

Edit: It seems some *other* application creates `WriteEvent` in global namespace before my app has a chance to do so. The (now) obvious workaround is to use some unique name or to use a GUID or whatever to avoid name collision.

Comment: Just to ask a stupid question; are you sure no other process is creating it on startup (your app or something else)? What happens if you change the name?

Comment: @Anders: This app lives only inside VS2019 and its debugger, no autostart of any kind. I don't know how I could determine if any other process is creating the event (I suppose WinDbg could do it but this is way above my skills). And if I change the events' name, say `WriteEvent1` in both the producer and consumer process everything works fine again. But that still leaves `WriteEvent` dangling around ...

Comment: Humans are just not very good at picking unique names, although you might have better odds with "john".  There is a simple and effect solution for that, in VS use Tools > Create GUID and copy/paste it into your code.

Comment: How can I find the process that created a particular event?

Comment: It's been a few days, has the problem `CreateEvent fails` been solved with GUID  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [`CreateEventW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventw) fails for a named object with error code `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` then that usually means that someone else created an event with that name already. In this case the system attempts to open the event object with `EVENT_ALL_ACCESS`. When this access mode is incompatible with the ACLs of the calling thread the API call fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

To work around this you will need to come up with a unique name for the event object. A common approach is to use the string representation of a GUID for the name. You can generate a GUID using the *guidgen.exe* tool from a Visual Studio Developer Command prompt.